# Can $k$-trees be regarded as intersection graphs?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[$k$-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-tree) is a special graph class of the [chordal graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph).
The chordal graph is a well-known graph class that can be regarded as an intersection graph of subgraphs of a tree.
I want to know whether $k$-tree can be regarded as an intersection graph of subgraphs of some special trees.

In fact, many subclasses of chordal graphs can be regarded as intersection graphs.
For instance, the split graph is an intersection graph of subgraphs of stars; the interval graph is an intersection graph of subgraphs of paths.